# Guess Riccati equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone guess solution to this Riccati equation $x'= x^2+\frac{x}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}, x=x(t)$ and can show his thought process.

Comment: Why would you think someone could "guess" it?  On the other hand, it can be [computed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%27%28t%29+%3D+x%28t%29%5E2+%2B+x%28t%29%2Ft+%2B+1%2Ft%5E2+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the coefficients of the equation have powers of $t$, a initial guess would be a constant multiple of a power of $t$: $x=at^k$.

Plugging in to the equation we find $k=-1$ and $a=-1$, that is $x=- \frac{1}{t}$ is an particular solution.

Note that this is an limit solution of the general solution found in the @Robert answer.